# Program that multiplies all prime numbers under 10 by 1,2,3,4,5

Tags: java

I already wrote some code and would like to know how to make all the prime numbers under 10, (2,3,5,7) to be multiplied by the first 5 digits above 0, (1,2,3,4,5). Here n on the 5th line would be the prime numbers under 10.

```
 package sct;


public class PrimeNumberMultiplicationTables {

    }
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                int n = ??? ;
                for(int i=1; i <= 5; i++)
                {
                    System.out.println(n+" multiplied by "+i+" = "+n*i);

           }
      }
}
```

Thank you in advance to whoever finds this.

Comment: Hint: you need an *array* of integers.   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Read the link I just provided you.  (A single `int` variable cannot represent 4 values at the same time .....)

Comment: Are you asking about how to find prime numbers? Or just about printing out multiplication tables?

Comment: Yes but I want to do it as if I didnt know the prime number to be able to customise the program and do it for example with prime numbers from 0 to 100 get it? I can't enter each of them in an array list, that would take forever. Could you please help me do that?

Comment: I think you need to back up a little bit, and think about this: how many prime numbers could come out of the configured range? Maybe none. What would you display? Maybe just 1. Would you display it as multiplied by 1 and 2 and 3, etc...? And if so, what if it was many primes? 

If you think about it that way, I assume that you need to take each prime (yeah, you really need an array of integers), then in your output, show them multiplied by each number in that second list.

Comment: @Hot - You have changed the requirements.  In the question *and* the title, you explicitly ask how to implement this for prime numbers under 10.   You really need to try to solve this for yourself.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here it is in C#, you can convert it to java.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            if (!IsPrime(i)) continue;

            for (var j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
            {
                var value = i * j;
                Console.WriteLine(i + " multiplied by " + j + " = " + value);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static bool IsPrime(int candidate)
    {
        if ((candidate & 1) == 0)
        {
            return candidate == 2;
        }

        for (var i = 3; (i * i) <= candidate; i += 2)
        {
            if (candidate % i == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return candidate != 1;
    }
}
```

Adding Java Version:

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        if (!IsPrime(i)) continue;

        for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
        {
            int value = i * j;
            System.out.println(i + " multiplied by " + j + " = " + value);
        }
    }
 }

public static boolean IsPrime(int candidate)
{
    if ((candidate & 1) == 0)
    {
        return candidate == 2;
    }

    for (int i = 3; (i * i) <= candidate; i += 2)
    {
        if (candidate % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return candidate != 1;
}
```

}

Comment: How do you convert it?

Comment: added the java version.

Comment: Thanks but can you explain it please? Just so I don't copy paste without understanding it. Btw what is candidate?

Comment: Please don't answer blatantly off-topic questions.